# Can I still craft my own spells?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

In previous games, there was a way for me to craft spells of varying degrees of effectiveness via spell-crafting stations.  Is there a way for me to do so in Skyrim?

Comment: There's a mod of this.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No there is not. It's possible to create your own potions with different effects, and to enchant items. But spell crafting is not possible within Skyrim.

Comment: sigh, I was pretty sure this was the case, but I had to check just in case.

Comment: If you're playing on PC, mods are your friend. There are tons of mods for spell crafting on the Steam workshop.

Answer (score 5):

There is no way in Skyrim to craft your own spells. Learning spells is strictly from spellbooks.

They probably removed spellmaking because of the obvious trouble someone could get into making 9 different feather spells, or a fireball that has an area of 50 feet.

Comment: It's a real shame. That was a lot of fun in Morrowind and Oblivion. Sure, junk spells would litter your menus and you could conceivably break the game's balance later, but you can already do that with alchemy and enchanting anyway. I fully expect a spellcraft mod later.

Comment: @Andy_Vulhop no doubt they will add a spellmaking system, though the animations for each spell would mostly be similar, as making completely new spell animations is difficult. And while you are waiting for a spellcraft mod i will be busy waiting for a multiplayer mod... heres hoping anyway

Comment: Obviously, the animations will be recycled. I wouldn't be surprised if several years out, people will be able to mod in new animations, but it's a little too top-of-the-line right now for the common man to create something that doesn't look out of place. I won't be all that upset about reused assets, though. Morrowind and Oblivion didn't give you unique animations for custom spells either.

Comment: as an aside, I can never understand the interest people have in playing Skyrim in a multiplayer setting. It's the quintessential single player experience, and I feel like it would be obnoxious having other people in your world. Not to mention how opening menus and such all pause the world. I wouldn't want either valid compromise to that. Letting someone pause everyone is garbage, and not letting you freeze the action when you hop into you favorites would also be unacceptable.

Comment: but, playing 2 player co-op with your friend would be awesome

Comment: I disagree. I prefer to find my own adventure, then talk with my friend excitedly IRL about our stories. It's like taking the mead hall into the real world.

Comment: @Jim, adding such content to somebody elses answer is usually frowned upon. However, you suggest an alternate method to achieve OPs goal. While I could not possible approve the edits, I would request you post your information as an answer.