# Can you craft your own spells in Skyrim?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I still craft my own spells?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/36044/can-i-still-craft-my-own-spells)

In Oblivion, you could craft your own skills at the Arcane University. Can this be done in Skyrim?

Comment: Aww. I looked for dupes before answering because I was sure I saw it, but I couldn't find it again.

Comment: You can do it by using mods but not in vanilla Skyrim.

Comment: Are you asking about vanilla Skyrim? Because it's not possible to do so unless you have a appropriate mod.

Answer (score 2):

Nope. You're stuck using the pre-made spells in Skyrim.

Luckily, the spells in Skyrim are more diverse than they ever were in Morrowind or Oblivion, so it seems like a fair trade.

Comment: I disagree that they're better. You had to hold and release and also the usage of magicka too. In oblivion you could cast a spell with a sword and shield. Skyrim no.